# Android: SQLite query with selection WHERE clause is not processed

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, android-contentresolver

I am trying to limit the database result by defining a SQL **WHERE** clause in the *selection* string of the query of the *ContentResolver*.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, getSelectionString(), null, null);
```

...

```
public String getSelectionString() {
    // TODO Replace latitude and longitude with database reference.
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    string.append("latitude >= ").append(northEast.getLatitudeE6() / 1e6);
    string.append(" AND ");
    string.append("latitude <= ").append(southWest.getLatitudeE6() / 1e6);
    string.append(" AND ");
    string.append("longitude >= ").append(southWest.getLongitudeE6() / 1e6);
    string.append(" AND ");
    string.append("longitude <= ").append(northEast.getLongitudeE6() / 1e6);
    return string.toString();
}
```

The database columns are defined as follows ...

```
public class CustomDatabase {
    public static final class Contract {
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    }
}
```

...

I am not particularly sure that I can inspect the query sent in cursor. If so, it does not contain the WHERE clause I sent:

```
SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM custom_db ORDER BY number ASC
```

Here is an example of the selection string:

```
latitude >= 48.203927 AND latitude <= 48.213851 AND longitude >= 16.36735 AND longitude <= 16.377648
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the WHERE clause syntactically correct?
2. Do I need apostrophs?
3. Am I forced to use both parameters (selection, selectionArgs) at a time in a query?
4. Where can I debug the whole query?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the *query()* method of the *ContentProvider* ...

```
public class CustomProvider extends ContentProvider {

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case URI_CODE_LOCATIONS:
            return mCustomDatabase.getLocations();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

... obviously, as [biegleux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300995/biegleux) guessed, I forgot to pass the parameters. Doh!
Here is the current implementation of the database method ...

```
public class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public Cursor getLocation() {
        return mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
            CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Do you suggest that I change the method signature to the following to pass all parameters? Am I not exposing to much of the database interface this way?

```
public Cursor getLocations(String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
    return mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(
            CustomSQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
}
```

Comment: it seems ok, can you post your provider's query() method?

Comment: Nice. You need to rewrite your comment as an answer so I can grant you the correct response.

Comment: BTW, not related to your issue, but a possible (slight) performance improvement, you could simplify the query by using the BETWEEN keyword.  `latitude BETWEEN #### AND #### AND longitude BETWEEN #### AND ####`

Comment: @Barak That is nice. I was not aware of this alternative. Thank very much, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it seems `query()` method of your provider is causing problems.
Make sure it looks like following.

```
@Override
public abstract Cursor query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
...

// run the query
db.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder, limit);
```

You are not forced to use `selectionArgs` parameter, but with it code is more readable.
To debug a query you can use

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
Log.e(TAG, qb.buildQuery(projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder, limit);
```

EDIT:
If you have a `ContentProvider` implemented you don't need to expose `getLocations()` method as you/users can use `ContentProvider's` `query()` method.
You should pass at least those arguments whose can be passed in `query()` method and those are `projection`, `selection`, `selectionArgs` and `sortOrder`.

Comment: Thank you. You comment was very helpful! So I limit the parameters to the following: `getLocations(String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String orderBy)` as I only can pass those through `Cursor.query()`. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This way you always get the same result regardless of which method of query() or getLocations() you call.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that line be:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, getSelectionString(), null, null);
```

Note the added parens after `getSelectionString` to indicate it's a method call, not a string (although I do wonder why that wouldn't throw an error as `getSelectionString` wouldn't exist as a string if my theory is correct...).